# Fortran 95 “Run time error - Inconsistent Interface”

Tags: python-3.x

```
 an(m+2,n)=fact1*an(m+1,n)-anm1(m,n)-fact2*(an(m+1,n+1)-fact2*(an(m+1,n-1))
```

I am defining my equation like this and it is giving error,

that Expected array subscript at (1), how I can sort out this error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anp(m+2,n)=fact1*an(m+1,n) &
                       -anm1(m,n)-fact2*an(m+1,n+1)
                       -fact2*an(m+1,n-1)

Comment: I have even changed my command like this but still it is saying invalid character at anp,anm and at fact2 ,please i am new in fortran please help .